# What causes Coherence X4 to open a second instance when in the Dock?

Tags: applications, dock

I am using an app called "Coherence X4" which makes full apps out of websites and it's way more advanced than the new feature Apple just released in macOS Sonoma which is barebones basic. The issue is when I drag the icon from the Finder/Applications or from Launchpad to my Dock it will open another instance of the app in order to open the app.

I just want it to open the app without this happening. I have worked with the developer they can't figure out why. If I pin it to the Dock by using "Keep in Dock" after I opened the original app from the Finder or Launchpad, it won't open and crash every time (which we also can't figure out either).

I've done a lot of digging and can't figure it out. If you happen to have experience in this area and might know why this is and could help out I be very appreciative of your time and help.

I have a [screen recording](https://app.box.com/s/3xh5f5zj0ey2bah9hkc4epzb8qx0a3qk) available to help give a general idea.